# Radio button's behaviour

Tags: javascript, dom

Im a DOM/javascript newbie trying to get my basics right. I'm just trying to observe radio button's behavior on clicking it. Heres my code.

HTML

```
    <script src="tmp.js"></script>
    <input type="radio" id="inp1" name="same" onclick="show();"/>
    <input type="radio" id="inp2" name="same" onclick="show();"/>
```

JS (tmp.js)

```
   function show() {
       alert(document.getElementById("inp1").value + " " + document.getElementById("inp2").value);
   }
```

What confuses me is that on running the alert box says "on on" on clicking either of the buttons. Shouldn't it be "on off" or "off on"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you want to get is `checked` property , have a look:

```
   function show() {
       alert( document.getElementById("inp1").checked + " " + 
              document.getElementById("inp2").checked);
   }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/w7vGL/

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't. The value is whatever you specify in the `value` attribute (and defaults to `'on'` for radio buttons if you fail to supply one).

Since only a checked radio button can be successful and sent to the server, changing the value is not needed (the data just won't be included when the form is submitted).

The checked status is stored in the `checked` property, and you can use that from JavaScript to determine which radio button is the currently checked one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the checked property, the value only determines what's inside when checked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        alert(document.getElementById("inp1").checked + " " + document.getElementById("inp2").checked);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" id="inp1" name="same" onclick="show();"/>
<input type="radio" id="inp2" name="same" onclick="show();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `checked` instead, but keep in mind that it will give you a boolean value, so the following code will do what you need:

```
function show() {
   alert(document.getElementById("inp1").checked ? 'on' : 'off'
 + " " + document.getElementById("inp2").checked ? 'on' : 'off'
   );
}
```